# select statement to multiply columns from one table then add column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select * from orders;
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| orderid | customerid | orderdate  | shipdate   | shipping | salestax |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
|       1 |          1 | 2008-03-31 | 2008-03-31 |     4.99 |     5.00 | 
|       2 |          1 | 2008-04-01 | 2008-04-02 |     5.99 |     5.00 | 
|       3 |          2 | 2008-04-01 | 2008-04-02 |     3.99 |     6.00 | 
|       4 |          3 | 2008-04-02 | 2008-04-02 |     6.99 |     7.50 | 
+---------+------------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
mysql> select * from orderinfo;
+---------+------------+-----+-------+----------+
| orderid | isbn       | qty | price | detailid |
+---------+------------+-----+-------+----------+
|       1 | 0929306279 |   1 | 29.95 |        1 | 
|       1 | 0929306260 |   1 | 49.95 |        2 | 
|       2 | 0439357624 |   3 | 16.95 |        3 | 
|       3 | 0670031844 |   1 | 34.95 |        4 | 
|       4 | 0929306279 |   1 | 29.95 |        5 | 
|       4 | 0929306260 |   1 | 49.95 |        6 | 
|       4 | 0439357624 |   1 | 16.95 |        7 | 
|       4 | 0670031844 |   1 | 34.95 |        8 | 
+---------+------------+-----+-------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

im trying to multiply the qty and price from the orderinfo table then add the shipping from the order table when i try to multiple them it works fine but when I add the shipping I get an incorrect value

this works

```
mysql> select orders.orderid,sum(orderinfo.qty*orderinfo.price) as order_total from orders
    -> inner join orderinfo
    -> on orders.orderid=orderinfo.orderid
    -> group by orderid;
+---------+-------------+
| orderid | order_total |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |       79.90 | 
|       2 |       50.85 | 
|       3 |       34.95 | 
|       4 |      131.80 | 
+---------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

this gives an incorrect value

```
mysql> select orders.orderid,sum(orderinfo.qty*orderinfo.price+orders.shipping) as order_total from orders
    -> inner join orderinfo
    -> on orders.orderid=orderinfo.orderid
    -> group by orderid;
+---------+-------------+
| orderid | order_total |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |       89.88 | 
|       2 |       56.84 | 
|       3 |       38.94 | 
|       4 |      159.76 | 
+---------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the `shipping` rate inside the `SUM()` aggregate, when really you need to add it afterward, to the result of the `SUM()`.  This has the effect of adding the `shipping` value for *each* row of the aggregated group, that is, double shipping for `orderid = 1` and 4x shipping for `orderid = 4`.

You can do this by adding `shipping` to the `GROUP BY` (actually MySQL doesn't require this, but it is good practice).

```
SELECT
  orders.orderid,
  /* Add `shipping` outside the SUM() aggregate */
  SUM(orderinfo.qty*orderinfo.price) + orders.shipping AS order_total 
FROM orders
  INNER JOIN orderinfo ON orders.orderid = orderinfo.orderid
GROUP BY
  orderid,
  shipping
```

#### [Here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e18e/1) on SQLFiddle.com.

Comment: Oh ok I was under the impression everything had to be within the ()

Comment: @dsquaredtech The aggregate is applied over the whole group, so in effect you are adding the `shipping` value for _each_ row if included inside the `SUM()`. Instead it needs to be applied just once outside.

Comment: I get it makes perfect sense now sometimes hard to think in the terms of how the mysql is interpreting it. Thanks.